# Is the speed of light the upper bound on CPU speed?

Tags: integrated-circuit, clock, cpu, speed

Edit: As this my first question in this site I was a bit confused how to pose the question. Because of the way I had put the question before has made it trouble to understand

What is the fastest speed that a CPU can ever reach without breaking the Laws of Physics? 
Is it determined by the speed of light only?

Are there any experiments or related articles published that describe how we can overcome limits imposed by the of speed of light or other phenomena? What is the highest clock frequency of a chip designed so far?

What is the max. speed that a CPU ever reached. What was that?

Comment: Speed of light in `m/s`, CPU performance in `Million Instructions Per Second (MIPS)` or `FLoating point Operations Per Second (FLOPS)`. How would we compare them objectively?

Comment: I think you already posted your own answer with: *Speed of Light - Overhead = Max speed of quantum computers*. Overheard > 0. From what little I remember reading about quantum entanglement, it still doesn't allow for transmission of information faster than light. See here: http://curious.astro.cornell.edu/question.php?number=612

Comment: I can see the seeds of several science fiction stories in here... "The Tomorrow Computer", and such. :-)

Comment: An interesting question would be: **What is the highest frequency a silicon CMOS CPU can reach?** I think it makes more sense, and the answer is not related to the speed of light, but rather on the technology node (gate length, dielectrics , semiconductor)

Comment: @RawBean I think it mostly depends on the power dissipation than the other things as we go for over clocking. For reference go through the link http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2392888,00.asp

Comment: @saikirangrandhi I think you are mixing different things. The maximum speed a CPU can reach is fixed by physic's law. The physic's laws of semiconductor. I don't blame you if you don't know them. The power dissipation is linked to the clock speed, yes it's true. But the power dissipation is not only linked to the clock speed (also voltage, doping..the list is tool long). Okay, maybe a given CPU has its speed depending on the power dissipation, because if it's getting too hot it will burn, but it's not a general case.

Comment: @RawBean Physics laws give the ideal speed possible. What power I am talking about is something like practically possible speed

Comment: @RawBean Can I have link to laws telling about the maximum speed achievable, is it >speed than light that was my question

Comment: Special relativity imposes the light speed limit on all forms of communication and interaction. http://abyss.uoregon.edu/~js/21st_century_science/lectures/lec06.html

Comment: @saikirangrandhi To go further in this question (which could be really interesting if you ask it differently) please define what do you mean by **CPU speed**? Do you mean the CPU clock frequency? If yes, how would you compare two things being of different types? You can't (scientifically speaking) compare a frequency (s-1) and a speed (m.s-1). See, the distance is missing here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Can the CPU can run faster than the speed of light?**

Information cannot travel between parts of a CPU faster than the speed of light. [Ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superluminal_communication)

> **I have seen a news saying that some quantum action is 10,000 times faster than light**

You (originally) linked to a [news article](http://www.livescience.com/27920-quantum-action-faster-than-light.html) which says

> Whereas the result may sound like a way to send faster-than-light messages, it isn't

Comment: Can I have an elaboration to the last sentence

Comment: @sai, the article says *"Whereas the result may sound like a way to send faster-than-light messages, it isn't, really, because you can't know the state of the entangled photon pair before it's measured; so there's no way to control it and make the photon at the other end take on certain states and use it like a Morse code telegraph."*

Comment: @sai: P.S. On Physics.stackexchange you may get better answers to questions about the implications of quantum entanglement for superluminal velocity.